# dealing with empty defaults in ant macrodefs

Tags: ant

Goal: macrodef a task based on `exec`, and make `timeout` optional in the defined task just as it is in the underlying `exec` task.

If I don't provide a default for `<attribute name="timeout"/>`, then ant requires a timeout.

If I provide a default of `""`, then the exec task complains.

Do I really need to create a conditional that asks if the timeout parameter has a value other than a silly default, and then have two copies of the exec invocation depending?

Comment: Did my other answer helped you? I have to know if I am to answer this one as well :)

Comment: I upvoted but didn't accept because I need to try it first. I had already implemented a work-around before you answered. Anyhow, I think the answer here is sufficient. I'm learning about <script>.

Comment: You could use ant-contrib conditional or write you own script or have a huge default value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see a clean way to do it without a conditional. But if you're not too fussy, you could go with a really long default value of timeout - e.g. a day or a week or a year's worth of milliseconds.